# how to append react div element from an array with a child element ? and how to give to mapped parent elements unique "key" props

Tags: reactjs, append, key, element

```
  const group = []
  for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      group.push(<div className="parent"></div>)
  }

  return (
    <>
      {group.map((item, i) => item )}
    </>
  );
}
```

here item will be `div` element with class name "parent", I want to put within it an element, and also I want to give to each item a unique key. (I tried returning from arrow function: `<item key={i}> <div className="child"></div> </item>` )

Answer (score 1):

For that to work your push should add a function component, which also render `children` props inside:

```
  const group = []
  for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      group.push((props) => <div className="parent">{props.children}</div>)
  }

  return (
    <>
      {group.map((Item, i) => <Item key={i}><div className="child">child {i}</div></Item> )}
    </>
 );
```